# populate 2nd dropdown based on selection of item in 1st dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have two drop down list ddl1,and ddl2.

Now on selecting an item of ddl1 the respective items in ddl2 should be populated.

Eg:- If I select "Accounts" in ddl1 then ddl2 should display "Account officer,Account manager,cheif financial officer" and similarly for other fields in ddl1. I wish to do this without any database connectivity( using ajax or Jquery ).There should be an xml file to store data's for dropdownlist. When we click on the 1st dropdown only dropdown portion of the page must be refreshed and also there should not be any php and .net codes.I need the full code to do like that.Please help me..........

Comment: use JSON instead of an XML files, it's easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
$(function(){
    var json ={'A':['Apple','Aeroplane','America'],'B':['Banana','BAT','BAG']};
    $('#alphabet').change(function(){
        if(this.value !=''){
            var arr = json[this.value];
            var option="";
            $.each(arr,function(k,v){
                option+='<option value="'+v+'">'+v+'</option>';
            })
            $('#spelling').html(option);
        }
    })

})
```

HTML CODE

```
<select id="alphabet">
    <option value="">SELECT</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
</select>
<select id="spelling"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your Json

```
{"Accounts": [
"Account officer",
"Account manager",
"Chief Financial Officer"],
"HR":[
"HR Head",
"Intern"]
}
```

and so on..